# Using sed to eliminate all lines that do not match the desired form

Tags: sed

I have a single column csv that looks something like this:

```
KFIG
KUNV
K~LK
K7RT
3VGT
```

Some of the datapoints are garbled in transmission.  I need to keep only the entries that begin with a capital letter, then the other three digits could be a capital letter OR a number.  For example, in the list above I would have to delete `K~LK` and `3VGT`.

I know that to delete all but capital letters I can write

```
sed -n '/[A-Z]\{4,\}/p'
```

I just want to adjust this to where the last three digits could be capital letters or numbers.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
sed -n '/[A-Z][A-Z0-9]\{3,\}/p'
```

However, if these identifiers are really all that there is in the file, I would propose the following command (it will assure that the whole line is matched, so it will reject for example identifiers more than 4 characters long):

```
sed -n '/^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]\{3\}$/p'
```

- `^` means "match zero-length string at the beginning of line";
- `\{3\}` means "match exactly 3 occurences of the previous atom", the previous atom being `[A-Z0-9]`;
- `$` means "match zero-length string at the end of line".

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer one way over the other?

Comment: In your case, yes — it's better to write an expression that matches full lines. For example the first expression would cause sed to print `3FOOB` if present in the input — because `FOOB` is matched. The second expression prevents that by trying to match the entire line.

Comment: However, if you are absolutely sure that no identifier in the input file contains more than four characters, then you can safely use first expression as well (or maybe a variant: `[A-Z][A-Z0-9]\{3\}`).